# SQL Server dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

In SQL Server, I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`, based on these I need to generate a report which is kind of very complex and after doing some research I come to a conclusion that I have to go with SQL Pivot table. Also, I tried this sample [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) but in my case the TableB table can have any number of child rows which makes it very complicated so, can anyone help me on this. Please see the details below:

Code

```
Create table TableA(
    ProjectID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlCode Varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    ControlPoint Decimal NULL,
    ControlScore Decimal NULL,
    ControlValue Varchar(50)
)
```

Sample Data

```
ProjectID | ControlID | ControlCode | ControlPoint | ControlScore | ControlValue
P001        1           A            30.44            65           Invalid
P001        2           C            45.30            85           Valid
```

Code

```
Create table TableB(
    ControlID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlChildID INT NOT NULL,
    ControlChildValue Varchar(200) NULL 
)
```

Sample Data

```
ControlID | ControlChildID | ControlChildValue
1           100              Yes
1           101              No
1           102              NA  
1           103              Others 
2           104              Yes
2           105              SomeValue
```

Output should be in a single row for a given ProjectID with all its Control values first & followed by child control values (based on the ControlCode (i.e.) ControlCode_Child (1, 2, 3...) and it should look like this

[image: Report format]

Comment: `I dont have any idea about the SQL Pivot feature` - what have you tried? Here on SO are plenty of question regarding using pivot - see related questions on the right side. Read them and the links, try something out and then ask when you are stuck.

Comment: Is there a standard set of child values? Or a max number of child values?

Comment: And what RDBMS is this?

Comment: @Hogan: There is no max number of child values and I am using SQL Server. Also, tried some samples but my situation is subtle.

Comment: @user972255 - If you don't have a max number of children then you won't be able to do this with a pivot, you will have to use dynamic SQL.  (Also true since you don't know the column names before the transformation).